# Kusto summarize unique occurrences of the value in the column

Tags: azure-data-explorer, summarize

I have following dataset:

```
let t1 = datatable(id:string, col1:string, col2:string)
[
    '1', 'ValueA', 'AT',
    '2', 'ValueC', 'AT',
    '3', 'ValueA', 'AT',
    '4', 'ValueB', 'AT',
    '1', 'ValueC', 'v-username',
];
t1 
| summarize (Id) by col1
```

My goal is to count occurrences of values in col1 per Id. Because ID=1 occurs twice, I need to decide whether to take ValueA or ValueC. This is decided by value of col2. If col2 startswith "v-" then take Value from this row. 
When I use "summarize (Id) by col1" I am getting:

```
ValueA,2
ValueC,2
ValueB,1
ValueD,1
Total:6
```

Expected result is:

```
ValueA,1
ValueC,2
ValueB,1
ValueD,1
Total:5
```

Is it possible to achieve with Kusto?

Answer (score 1):

a. when you run `... | summarize (id) by col1" you should get a semantic error as there's no aggregation function specified (e.g. you could have run`... | summarize dcount(id) by col1`)

b. it's not clear where `ValueD, 1`, in your expected result, come from. as your `datatable` expression includes no record with `ValueD`

c. if i had to guess the solution to your question, despite *a* and *b*, this would be my guess:

```
let t1 = datatable(id:string, col1:string, col2:string)
[
    '1', 'ValueA', 'AT',
    '2', 'ValueC', 'AT',
    '3', 'ValueD', 'AT',
    '4', 'ValueB', 'AT',
    '1', 'ValueC', 'v-username',
];
t1 
| summarize c = dcount(id) by col1
| as T
| union (T | summarize c = sum(c) by col1 = "Total")
```